# Libgdx - How to close Dialog and continue operations on current screen?

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a problem with closing the Dialog. I can close it, but I have to press the button more than once. I have two buttons and one that is used for closing the application works fine, but the second one for closing the dialog doesn't work properly.

The button: `button("No", "continue");`

I'm using remove() method in overriden method result(Object object) when a parameter object is equal to "continue".

```
@Override
protected void result(Object object) {
    if (object.equals("exit")){
        Gdx.app.exit();
    }
    else if (object.equals("continue")){
        remove();
    }
}
```

I have also tried to use `hide(null);` but I got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working dialog code for "Are you sure you want to quit?"

```java
Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Exit", Assets.skin1) {
    @Override
    protected void result(Object object) {
        if ((Boolean) object) {
            Gdx.app.exit();
        }else{
            //not necessary but if dialog not hide, call hide() here
            //hide();
        }
    }
};
dialog.text("Are you sure you want to quit?");
dialog.button("Yes", true).button("No", false);
dialog.getContentTable().pad(20);
dialog.getTitleTable().pad(20);
dialog.padTop(60); // set padding on top of the dialog title
dialog.setModal(true);
dialog.setMovable(false);
dialog.setResizable(false);

dialog.show(stage);
```

"No" button will close the dialog.